# Where to store data files in WinStore app (win32 Project Centennial)

Tags: windows, desktop-bridge

I am porting my native Win32 app to Windows 10 Store with Desktop App Convertor.

What is the most recommended place to store local data files,  it seems %APPDATA% works, but is it most recommended place for user data in Win10 Store Apps?

Is this %appdata% virtualized and cleaned automatically  if user uninstall app from Win Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%LOCALAPPDATA% is new requirement to be compatible with store

Answer (score 1):

If the data has to be saved per Windows user (every windows user has its own data) then it is the right place

The saved data will not be cleaned up when the user uninstall the app

Comment: Is there a folder  that would be cleaned automatically when STORE APP is uninstalled?

Comment: applications converted by DAC does not handle it automatically in any way
you have to delete the your application data folder during the uninstall procedure

Comment: according to microsoft site, the appdata is virtualized ?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the meaning of your question.